# PayPal options os2, os3, etc. do not appear in transaction details?

Tags: html, forms, paypal, paypal-buttons

My first two options are being passed to the transaction details without a problem. The phone and address.

For the rest of the options only the title (on2, on3, etc) pass to the details. The value (os2, os3, etc) come through as N/A.

```html
<form class="paypalform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"> <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mybussiness.sanbox@email.com"> <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://website.com" />
<p><label>First Name:<span class="required">*</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </label></p>
<p><label>Last Name:<span class="required">*</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </label></p>
<p><label>Email:<span class="required">*</span><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </label></p>
<p><label>Phone:<br>
 <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Phone" /><input type="text" name="os0" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false"> </label></p>
<p><label>Address:<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Address" /><textarea name="os1" cols="40" rows="5" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></label></p>
<p><label>Please pick a item:<span class="required">*</span></label><br><label><input type="radio" name="item_name" value="item1" checked="checked"> Item1 </label><label><input type="radio" name="item_name" value="item2"> Item2 </label><label><input type="radio" name="item_name" value="item3"> Item3 </label><label><input type="radio" name="item_name" value="Beth Shalom Donation: Pillar of Community"> Item4 </label><label><input type="radio" name="item_name" value="item5"> Item5 </label></p>
<p><label>Please type your message below. It will appear in print and/or online:<br>
 <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Message" /><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" aria-invalid="false" name="os2"></textarea></label></p>
<p><label>Amount:<span class="required">*</span><br>
   <span class="dollarsign">$</span><input type="number" name="amount"  min="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></label></p>
<p><label>Acknowledge to be sent to:<br>
 <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Acknowledge to be sent to" /><input type="text" name="acknowledge" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" name="os3"></label></p>
<p><label>Recipient's Email:<br>
 <input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Recipient's Email" /><input type="email" name="recipient-email" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" name="os4"></label></p>
<p><label>Recipient's Phone:<br>
 <input type="hidden" name="on5" value="Recipient's Phone" /><input type="text" name="recipient-phone" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" name="os5"></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. I have two name="" on the field options. I removed one of them and left the name="os2" and it is working.